# jQuery in Google Chrome Content Script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How would I go about including the jQuery library in my Google Chrome Content Script? I have tried, fruitlessly, of course. Should I use `<script src="..." /></script>`, or is there a different/better way to go about it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You need to load it in your manifest.json, like this:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.4.2.js", "extension.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Putting in the background.html doesn't do... but it's mandatory, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for this. For anyone doing this but still not getting it to work, make sure that jQuery is the first one listed.

Comment: @DanibISHOP - No. The background.html page is just for code that runs in the background. Content scripts are in a separate DOM context and run on the actual page and only communicate with the background page using postMessage or the Chrome messaging APIs.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi Content scripts are agnostic of scripts running on the main page, and vice-versa. See Google's page on content scripts, [in particular, the Execution Environment section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). "They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page...The same is true in reverse: JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any variables defined by content scripts."

Comment: @p0lar_bear I recently experienced it, you are right. Thanks for the update anyway,.

Comment: Is it necessary to have Jquery script file?

Comment: My question is, after including jQuery in the manifest file, do I still need to inject into the page to use it?