# how to put jquery on the option page extension chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension with options page, I want to put on the page options jquery , I insert the jquery in options.html this way.

```
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
```

this form does not work WHAT should I do?

My manifest

```
{
 "name": "Compra Protegida",
 "options_page": "options/options.html",
 "version": "1.6",
 "description": "Alerta usuários ao acessar sites de compras virtuais não recomendado pelo Reclame Aqui ou presentes na Lista do Procon. ",
 "background" :  { 
 "scripts" :  [ "background.js" ] 
 } , 
"page_action": {
"default_icon": "19.png",
"default_title":"Site não recomendado",
"default_popup":"popup.html"
},
"permissions" : [
"tabs"
],
"icons" : {
"48" : "48.png",
"128" : "128.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the actual jQuery you are using is in a separate script. ie. `<script src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>` for including jQuery and ALSO `<script src="optionsJS.js"></script>` for the jQuery ***you*** want to use. You cannot have any inline `<script>` tags in a Chrome extension other than `<script src...>` tags.

Comment: everything is right with my jquery, only the css is working <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" media="screen" /> jquery no sign

Comment: Have you linked to an external js file containing your jquery code? Can you post your options.html page?

Comment: everything is connected properly do not know why does not work, will be should I use content script in the manifest for jquery files?

Comment: If you want to use jQuery in your content script see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209790/jquery-in-google-chrome-content-script).

Comment: Presumably you have included jquery.js as well as jquery.tablesorter.min.js? As the user above asked, if you can post your options.html this will help us help you better.

Comment: friends I managed to fix my mistake, I put a script embedded in options.html and find here at stackoverflow which is not allowed inline script, I created a file with the script and put in options.html, worked, thank you for the help and the the provision of you: D