# Calling content_script.js custom event from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, chromium

In my content_script.js for a chrome extension I'm working on I have:

```
document.addEventListener("funcDoRequest", function (params)
{
    alert('From content_script');
});
```

In my index.html web page how do I call this funcDoRequest from jQuery?  Any examples?  I need to pass detail.x parameters to it too.

I can do it like this without jQuery but I don't want this:

```
<script>
    var event = new CustomEvent('funcDoRequest', { 'detail': { something: 'something' } });
    var go = function () { document.dispatchEvent(event); }
</script>
<a href="javascript:go();">Click me</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: _"I can do it like this without jQuery but I don't want this"_ Is requirement to substitute for jQuery version of javascript at Question? What is purpose of using jQuery to perform task that you are currently able to achieve without using jQuery?

Comment: I was assuming jQuery would provide a more elegant way to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it is possible using jQuery. Not sure how to determine or what criteria is for is "more elegant" approach than another approach? Is requirement of Question for a jQuery solution?

Comment: I just want do something like jQuery('body').trigger('funcDoRequest');  Why don't that work?

Comment: _"I just want do something like jQuery('body').trigger('funcDoRequest'); Why don't that work?"_ Event appears attached to `document`, not `body` at `js` at Question? See post

Comment: I see that now.  I'm an amateur.  So why doesn't this work? 
jQuery("#clickme").on("click", function () {
  jQuery(document).trigger('funcDoRequest');
});
<a href="#" id="clickme">Click me</a>
with my content_script.js having document.addEventListener("funcDoRequest", function (intralaunch)
{ alert('test'); }
Why the hell can't I add code to comments here too..???

Comment: `<a>` element at Question does not appear to have `id` `"clickme"` ? Is jQuery loaded at `document`?

Comment: _"Why the hell can't I add code to comments here too..???"_ Try wrapping code in backticks

Answer (score 0):

A possible jQuery equivalent approach could set `.click()` event at `<a>` element, using `.on()` with `"funcDoRequest"` as custom event; calling `.trigger()` with `"funcDoRequest"` as first parameter, data object `{ something: "something" }` as second parameter at click on `a` element ; where data object passed can be accessed at `.on("funcDoRequest")` handler as second argument `params`. Also added `event.preventDefault()` at `a` click handler.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var doc = $(this); // `document`
    $("a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      doc.trigger("funcDoRequest", {
        "something": "something"
      })
    });
    // at `content_script.js`
    $(document).on("funcDoRequest", function(e, params) {
      console.log(e, params);
      alert(JSON.stringify(params))
    });
  })
</script>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
```

Comment: @KenWilliams Can you describe "doesn't seem to work"? Is jQuery loaded at `document`? , at content script?

Comment: It just does nothing.  Not even a javascript console error.  jQuery is loading fine everywhere.  To me this should work should it not?

`// index.html
jQuery("#clickme").on("click", function ()
{
     jQuery(document).trigger('funcDoRequest');
});
<a href="#" id="clickme">Click me</a>`

`// content_script.js
document.addEventListener("funcDoRequest", function (intralaunch)
{
    alert('Here in content_script');
});`
This is stupid, I can't even add new lines.

Comment: How is jQuery loaded at `document` ? and at `content_script.js` Are you sure jQuery is defined at both?

Comment: No, `.trigger()` would not call event at `document.addEventListener("funcDoRequest", function (intralaunch) { alert('Here in content_script'); })`

Comment: yes, definitely being loaded, I test with alert('test'); in jQuery(document).ready(function()) for both and I get the javascript alert.

Comment: @KenWilliams Is jQuery listed in `manifest.json` ?, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209790/jquery-in-google-chrome-content-script . Why are you using `document.addEventListener` instead of `$(document).on()` at `content_script.js` ?

Comment: Yes, its listed in content_script.js.  I don't know why I'm using document.addEventListner instead of document.on(), I thought they were cross compatible.  I ended up just doing this `jQuery("#clickme").on("click", function ()
       {
           document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('funcDoRequest', { 'detail': { paramname: 'paramval' } }));
       });`

Comment: Have you tried with `js` at post at `// at content_script.js` ?

Comment: I'm not following you with `js`.  Have I tested jquery in content_script.js?  It works fine, yes.   jQuery is added to the manifest.json too.  I've concluded its not getting better then my comment above I think..  thanks for your help.